# Adding custom permission to Django Rest Framework Function-Based view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I am trying to write a custom `IsOwner` permission for a DRF function based view that has a parameter of `user_id`. The view is as follows:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly])
def return_credibility(request, user_id):
    credibility = utils.get_credibility(user_id)
    return Response({'id': user_id, 'credibility': credibility})
```

Except I would want to replace `permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` with my custom `IsOwner` permission.
I tried writing something like this:

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.id == view.user_id
```

Except I am not sure how to access the user_id property from the view. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `user_id` from `view.kwargs`.

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.id == view.kwargs['user_id']
```